# Comparing the Values of Two HTML Forms using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have two separate forms that have identical attributes.  Is there an eloquent way to compare their values for equivalence using JS/Jquery?

`$('#form1').context.forms[0] === $('#form2').context.forms[0]` seems to work but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

I am using spring/thymeleaf to generate the contents of the forms.

Comment: I don't see how that comparison can ever work. It's not comparing the contents of the form, it's just telling whether they're the same DOM element.

Comment: You could use `$("#form1').html() === $('#form2').html()`

Comment: It seems my current solution is incorrect and will always return true.

Comment: It should always return false.

Comment: Do you want to compare the HTML contents or the input values?

Comment: @Barmar the input values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `context` is the entire `document`, because that's the default value when you don't pass the `context` argument to [`$(selector, context)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context). So your code is basically doing this:

```
document.forms[0] === document.forms[0] // Always true
```

If you want to compare the field values in these forms, you can use [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
$('#form1').serialize() === $('#form2').serialize() // Implies fields are in the same order
```

**Demo**

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var identical = $('#form1').serialize() === $('#form2').serialize();
  alert(identical ? "Values are identical" : "Values are NOT identical");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input name="name">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="accepts_tou">
    Do you accept out Terms of use?
  </label>
</form>
<form id="form2">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input name="name">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="accepts_tou">
    Do you accept out Terms of use?
  </label>
</form>

<button>Compare</button>
```

Comment: that's pretty slick